# Trying to save an image with Vue.js and axios on Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using Laravel 5.5, Vue.js and axios.

I am generating a canvas image from a particular  element. The code for saving an image:

```
        save(url) {
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');
        html2canvas(element, {
            proxy: url,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                console.log(image);
                Vue.axios.post('/add', {
                    image: image,
                  })
                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
                // downloadURI("data:" + image, "yourImage.jpg");
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the code from controller:

```
    public function addPost(Request $request) {
    $photo = $request->file('image');
    $path = $photo->store('img');
    return 'something';
}
```

But all I am getting is this error: `Call to a member function store() on null`. So the error is in $path.

I have tried with `if($request->hasFile('image'))` but it doesn't do nothing. What should I do, so I can store generated image to my public derictory?

Comment: have you tried to `dd($request->all())`? What does it show?

Comment: @Wreigh I get array:1 [
  "image" => "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgw......
] 

Which I assume is OK, but now I need to save it...

Comment: `$request->file('image')` is `null`, I think it has something to do on how you upload the file, because Laravel didn't parse the data right, that's why it is `null` (I think!)